# can I create an scaffold from my schema.rb on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create the scaffold (with all the methods and all) for a new table I created, its on my DB and I already added to my schema.rb, but I dont know what to do know, does somebody know the command I should run or something similar? Ive found options from db to schema, but not from schema.rb to scaffolds.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would highly recommend you to read this article:
[Getting up and running quickly with scaffolding](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding)

I'm not quite sure if I understand properly to your question. But as far I know you're doing definitely something wrong. The scaffolding is done for example by command:

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string title:string bio:text
```

You wrote that you already created table in DB. So this indicates me, that you're not following the scaffolding, or more important Rails, principles. If you manually added table into the database.

**Go ahead and read the Getting Started Guide it will help you.**

Comment: Thank you!! I tried something like that but didnt created all fields, I am not sure if after that I had to run bundle exec rake db:migrate as I did... but some fields were missing, and now nothing is working

Comment: after the rails generate you need to run rake db:migrate . This will update our database and create there the latest table.

Answer (score 0):

You usually use schema.rb as a convenient way to see table and columns you have in you database.

Scaffold creates new table when you ran it, like rails g scaffold Post name:string, where Post is a name for model(post.rb), for controller(posts_controller.rb) and database table named posts with column name which is string.(look it up in schema after rake db:migrate)

In your project initiate scaffold and find schema to see that it's table is already in place.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
scaffold -c -p db/schema.rb
```

this will generate a list of commands you'll execute to generate your Model View Controller components.

However, this dont insert the qualifiers (has_many, belongs_to, etc..) on models.

I wonder if is there an option to enable this from the foreign keys listed on schema.rb

Answer (score 0):

Use this gem https://github.com/frenesim/schema_to_scaffold

```
Usage: scaffold [options] 

Generate a rails scaffold script for a given schema.rb
 -h             Displays help.
 -p <path>      It specifies a path to a folder or to a file.
 -c             Will copy the script to your clipboard. Requires xclip be installed on Linux.
 -f             Generates a factory_girl:model rather than a full scaffold.
 -m             Add migration (use if your schema comes from a different database)

Examples:
scaffold
scaffold -c -p ~/work/rails/my_app
scaffold -c -p ~/work/rails/my_app/db/schema.rb
```